# Get the MSI Name during installation

Tags: c#

I am making an MSI for one of the WPF application using Installer Service class.

Lets say abc.msi has been created. Now i have changed its name from abc to def.msi.

I want to extract the name of msi at the time of MSI installation in  Install Method of InstallerService class.

Answer (score 0):

This will likely do what you're after:

```
Path.GetFileName(Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()[1])
```

Comment: its not working. Its giving the same msi.exe not the MSI name

Comment: Try changing the 0 to a 1.